# Grabbing text between slashes in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet and was trying to figure out if there was a way to grab text b/w slashes.

For example:

[In cell B9]
R:\FINANCE-Asia\Q1Report.html

I want to pull out:  FINANCE-ASIA and place it into cell C9.

Anybody know what the formula for this would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by no means a 'clean' method of going about it; and would only apply to finding the first set of text.

=LEFT(RIGHT(B9, LEN(B9)-FIND("\",B9)),FIND("\",B9, FIND("\",B9)+1)-FIND("\",B9)-1)

Slightly cleaner form:
=MID(B9, FIND("\",B9)+1, FIND("\",B9, FIND("\",B9)+1)-FIND("\",B9)-1)

Answer (score 0):

Even cleaner form:

```
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(B9, "\", 2), "\", 1)
```

It'll give you the text before the 2nd backslash and after the 1st backslash.